# Setting Knowledge data category visibility based on Partner Roles

Tags: lightning, lightning-knowledge

We have several Partner accounts and their hierarchies(point of Sales). Partner account can have multiple child partner accounts.
for e.g
PartnerAccount 1 => Pos1, Pos 2
PartnerAccount 2 => Sop1, Sop2

On the other hand, we have data category created for each partner(main partner account).
Knowledge articles created under Partner account should be visible to their child partner accounts part of same hierarchy.

To implement this, we are thinking to maintain a mapping of data category and POS Partner Accounts.

Can we assign knowledge data category on portal roles using apex/flow? I tried to find out any objects/methods but could not find any.